# How to write Java MUnit tests with MUnit 2.1 and Mule 4.1

Tags: java, mule, anypoint-studio, munit

I have started moving from Mule 3.9 to 4.1, which means moving to Anypoint Studio 7 and MUnit 2.1

Previously, in MUnit 1.3 it was easy to create automated test suites in Java by extending the `FunctionalMunitSuite` class and following the instructions in the official Mule doco here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/v/1.3/munit-tests-with-java.

I cannot find a similar approach using MUnit 2.1, the documentation only describes writing the test suites using the graphical/xml approach: https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/v/2.1/

I find writing java MUnit tests much more reliable and extendable, does anyone have any experience doing this with MUnit 2.1? Specifically, how can I write Java based MUnit or JUnit tests in Mule 4 without needing to revert to the graphical test suites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java based tests are not currently supported in MUnit 2.x.

Comment: Yes, I had the same response from Mule support - feel free to vote for the feature to be included here: https://support.mulesoft.com/s/ideas#08734000000bnJuAAI